# Why a flutter plugin not working in code?

Tags: flutter

Few days back ,I am practicing UI design in which I use plugin of simple animation in which tween need to declare at place of variable for assigning the complete animation but in between coding I get an error that this animation is not supported so I am just want to understand why it is displaying at website https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations  but not working in code .

Comment: Can you add the code that isn't working for you? Can you add the code that does work from your link? This would allow people to understand more clearly what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the older version of the plugin. Maybe that is the issue